# Does $(a+b)^p \leq 2^{p-1}(a^p+b^p)$ stand also when we have minus?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

It stands that $$(a+b)^p \leq 2^{p-1}(a^p+b^p)$$

Does it also stand when we have $"-"$ instead of $"+"$ ??

Does it stand that $$|f_n-f|^p \leq (|f_n|^p+|f|^p)$$ ??

($f_n, f \in L^p, 1 \leq p <+\infty$)

Comment: What are $f_n$ and $f$ ?

Comment: @Peter $f_n ,f \in L^p, 1 \leq p <+\infty$

Comment: Must $p$ be a natural number ?

Comment: @Peter $p$ is a real number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just note that

$$
|f_n - f| \leq |f_n| + |f|.
$$

Now use the additive version.

Comment: What do you mean with "additive version" ??

Comment: The version with "$+$" instead of "$-$", i.e. $(|f_n| + |f|)^p \leq 2^{p-1} ( |f_n|^p + |f|^p)$. My answer assumes that you are only really interested in the $|f_n  - f|^p$ estimate, not in $(a-b)^p$ in general. The general $(a-b)^p$ estimate has some problems, for example if $a - b < 0$ and $p \notin \Bbb{Z}$, then $(a-b)^p$ is not even defined (as a **real** number). Also, in the $|f_n - f|^p$ estimate, you will have to introduce the term $2^{p-1}$ on the RHS. To see this, use $f = -f_n$.

Comment: So, is it as followed: $$|f_n-f|^p \leq (|f_n|+|f|)^p \leq 2^{p-1} (|f_n|^p+|f|^p)$$ ??

Comment: Yes, this is exactly right (assuming $p>0$).

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!!! :-)